# What is "passive participle"?

Tags: grammar

This post is derived from my another post ([Could some help analyze the structure of this sentence "Sleet is *rain and snow mixed together*"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239455/109190)), where a nice guy @James  answers

> That noun phrase has a participle "mixed", which functions passively: the object of "mixed" is "rain and snow" (in **passive participle** phrases the grammatical subject is the logical object).

where the term **passive participle** is used, and I don't have a clear understanding about the concept.

Another ELL post ([Formation of passive participle clause](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/107171/109190)) considers the following sentence as an example of **passive participle clause**

> After being arrested, he was taken to the police station.

according which, 'being+p.p' is the **passive participle clause**.

However, another [post](https://www.insegnanti-inglese.com/grammar-1/participles.html) gives this explanation

> John was eaten by lions. (here, eaten is a passive participle)

Which is simply a passive voice sentence.

So, what is "passive participle"? Is it a canonical term in English grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle#Types_of_participle)*

> **Participles** may also be identified with a particular voice: **active** or **passive**. Some languages (such as Latin and Russian) have distinct participles for active and passive uses. In English, the **present participle** is essentially an active participle, while the *past participle* has both active and passive uses.
>
> The following examples illustrate this:
>
> 1. I saw John **eating** his dinner. (Here *eating* is an **active present participle**).
> 2. The bus has gone. (Here *gone* is an active past participle).
> 3. The window *was* **broken** with a rock. (Here *broken* is a **passive past participle**)

Comment: Thank you! I guess your examples are similar to the ones in the link in my OP (the eaten series). I updated my OP. So, are "passive participle" and " Passive voice" the same?

Comment: @WXJ96163  I answered the **original** question not a different question, please do not change it.

Comment: @WXJ96163: No, they are not. _Passive voice_ is a property of certain grammatical constructions (in some languages, certain grammatical words); or is loosely applied to the constructions which have that property. _Passive participle_ is a class of words. In English and some other languages, all passive constructions (i.e. constructions which express passive voice) include a passsive participle.

Comment: @ColinFine Thank you. Would you please move your comment to [my new question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239473/109190), since that turns out to be a different question.

Answer (score 0):

The past participle of transitive verbs is passive, that of intransitive verbs is active.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but you might consider explaining a bit more. If you look at the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site, you will see that here we tend to give more through explanations than that.