# Are "passive participle" and " Passive voice" the same thing in Modern English?

Tags: grammar

The following examples from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle) illustrate what is "passive participle"

> The bus has gone. (Here *gone* is an active past participle).
>
> ex_1: The window *was* **broken** with a rock. (Here *broken* is a **passive past participle**)

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/passive-voice?q=Passive%20voice) gives these examples

> Cambridge University Press published this book. (active)
>
> ex_2: This book was published by Cambridge University Press. (passive)

I can't see the difference between ex_1 and ex_2.

Are "passive participle" and " Passive voice" the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In short:**

Participle is a form of a verb that can be used, among other things, to create tenses and the passive voice. When a participle is used to create passive voice, it can be called "passive participle."

In the sentence:

> The window was broken with a rock.

...the *word* broken is a participle and the *sentence* is in the passive voice.

**A bit more about participles:**

According to [YourDictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/participle), the word participle refers to a verb that can be used as:

- adjective (broken window)
- verb (seeing the results, he stopped)
- noun (seeing is believing)
- adverb (raving mad)
- with an auxiliary verb "have" or "be" to indicate tense, aspect, or voice:

  - *I have asked.* (present tense, perfect aspect)
  - *I am asking.* (present tense, progressive aspect)
  - *I am asked.* (present tense, passive voice)

The **present participle** ends in -ing (asking) and the **past participle** most commonly ends in -ed or -en (asked, spoken).

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation. "passive participle" is used to construct passive voice, that is the relationship between them. So, those are 2 different concepts, right?

Comment: @WXJ96163,  yes, "passive participle" is only a word, while passive voice is on the sentence level (when the subject is "acted upon" by some other performer, like in _The window was broken by a rock_). To know if a word is a participle, you need to know only that word, but to know if the passive voice is used, you need to know the entire clause.

Comment: The term "passive participle" is confusing. It does not exclusively pertain to the passive voice although it is used with some form of the verb "be" to form the passive voice. It is also used with with some form of the verb "have" to form the perfect tenses. Thus, it is also called the "perfect participle." Because, for most verbs, the form of this participle is the same as the form used for the simple past tense, it is also called the "past participle." Do not let the names confuse you: the numerous uses of this kind of participle are **NOT** determined by which name it is referred to.

Comment: @JeffMorrow, I intended to add that "passive participle" is not really an "official" grammatical term in English, but I was not sure. It only ads to confusion.

Comment: @Jan The vocabulary seems designed to bewilder the student. None of the terms usually used indicates the wide variety of ways that this kind of participle is used. Of them all, I think past participle is the worst because it confuses the distinction between a verb and a part of a verb that can also be used independently as a noun, adjective, or adverb.

Comment: @JeffMorrow: since there's no single descriptive name to cover all the uses, the alternative seems to be to give them descriptive names based on forms (e.g., -ed and -ing participles, but not every word built with these suffixes is a participle and not every -ed participle ends with -ed; or -en participles, even though more end with -ed than -en), or to give them completely non-descript names (German does this: the forms corresponding to -ing and -en participles are called Partizip I and Partizip II) but then the names have absolutely *no* mnemonic value and I find them very hard to remember

Comment: @Max You are correct. I would propose **progressive participle** and **perfect participle** as being correctly descriptive of **FORM** in every case. This does not indicate function, but participles have multiple functions. However, I doubt that I am in a position to make an effective proposal that will overturn centuries of confusing nomenclature.

Answer (score 5):

[Your own Wikipedia link has the answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle#Modern_English):

> The past participle, **also sometimes called the passive or perfect participle,** is identical to the past tense form (ending in -ed) in the case of regular verbs, ...

In English the *passive voice* is formed using the conjugated form of the verb *be* followed by the *past participle* of the main verb. That is why such a participle is sometimes also called a *passive participle*.