# "The dinner was eaten by John", does it sound right?

Tags: word-usage

Consider this one

> Alice was eaten by that lion.

I am pretty sure it is both grammatical and idiomatic.

Consider this sentence

> John ate his dinner.

I am 100% certain it is grammatical and idiomatic. How about this one?

> The dinner was eaten by John.

I am also 100% certain it is grammatical. However, I am not so sure if it is idiomatic. Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

---

**Note:** I am aware the concept of active voice and passive voice, I just don't really understand the usage.

---

The examples are adapted Another post ([What is "passive participle"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239460/109190)).

Comment: Always use *active voice* if possible. ('The dinner was eaten by John' is **not** the passive of 'John is eating his dinner')

Comment: The upside is, the lion isn't hungry any more. Neither is Alice.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this question have got no easy answer, in my opinion it's to broad and should be closed.

But let me explain the reasons using more words that a comment can contain.

All quotes has been take from the Oxford Dictionary:

[**idiomatic**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/idiomatic)

> Using, containing, or denoting expressions that are **natural**
>   to a native speaker

**[natural](https://www.lexico.com/definition/natural)**

> 2. In accordance with the nature of, or circumstances surrounding, someone or something
>      2.2(of a skill or quality) coming **instinctively** to a person; innate

[**instinctively**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/instinctively)

> Without **conscious** thought; by natural **instinct**

A native speaker **feels** that something does not sound right but he can not explain exactly why, by the self definition of **idiomatic**.

You are a native speaker of your languague, even if it's not English you should know what I mean.

Comment: So, the last example in my OP is not "**not idiomatic**", it just does not sound right. Is my understand right?

Comment: @WXJ96163 That's my opinion. I think that your question does not involve just your example but all other non-idiomatic phrases as well. To get what I mean just think about that sentence in your own language and play with the different ways of expressing it. You may find some non-idiomatic possibilities.

Comment: It's not so much that it doesn't sound right, but I can't imagine any circumstances in which one would say it that way round.

Comment: @KateBunting Well, I was over-simplifying, it's not a matter of something just sounding right. That's the reason for my vote to close. Too broad + opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

"The dinner was eaten by John" might be used in the situation where there was a question about who had eaten the dinner,  and the sentence is identifying that it was John. Otherwise, you would just say something like "John ate the dinner [and then went to bed]."