# To be bitten vs. bitten. Which one is correct?

Tags: passive-voice

**i dont want to be bitten by a snake**

**i dont want bitten by a snake**

which of above sentences are correct? Is it necessary to us **to be**? what happens if i don't use it?

Comment: You must always capitalize **I** in English when you are referring to yourself, and don't forget the apostrophe in **don't**!

Answer (score 5):

Only "I don't want **to be** bitten by a snake" is correct.

Yes, it is necessary to use **to be**.  *Want* can only be used with a noun phrase (like "I want *some antivenom*") or the *to*-infinitive of a verb (like "I want *to see* a tiger").  **Bitten** is a past participle.

If you don't use it, your sentence sounds wrong and non-fluent.

Reference: [Using want](https://www.englishgrammar.org/using-want/)

Answer (score 0):

"I don't want bitten by a snake" is incorrect in standard English, but such a construction might be used in some regional dialects especially [in Scotland, Appalachia, and the American Midwest](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/needs-washed).

In these dialects, "need" or "want", and occasionally "like", can be followed directly by a [passive participle](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/239460/what-is-passive-participle) instead of the standard [to-infinitive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/to-infinitive) or other phrasing.

> [Does your road still **need plowed**?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QF4iRTxG5Zk)

(Standard: "need to be plowed" or "need plowing")

> The cats **like fed** dinner by 4:30.

(Standard: "like to be fed" or "like (it) if they're fed")

Comment: Why are you including Scotland in your list of places, the references only mentions North America

Comment: Welcome to ELL. I hope you like the place and decide to visit often. You might want to [take the tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) or to read the [Contributor's guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4783/91457). The guide has a lot of helpful information on how best to ask, and answer, questions here on ELL.