# "Here is a sentence which I think an example of passive participle clause", is it grammatical?

Tags: grammar

To figure out [the concept of "passive participle"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239460/109190), I am learning an ELL post ([Formation of passive participle clause](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/107171/109190)), which starts with

> Here is a sentence *which I think an example* of passive participle clause

the part "which I think an example" seems not grammatical.

I guess it could be like this

> Here is a sentence *which **is** I think an example* of passive participle clause

Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fully understand the Passive Voice, see the example from the question linked in your post:

> “…he **was taken** to the police station”

The words in bold are in the ***past* passive voice**.

Who took the man to the police station? Presumably one or more police officers, but it is not an important detail hence the writer chose the passive voice.  The equivalent in the active voice would be

> …they (the police officers) **took** him to the police station.

To construct the passive voice, we need the auxiliary verb "be" and the *past participle* of the main verb, in this case the PP of the verb  *take* is ***taken***.

## **PASSIVE**

1. He **is taken** to the station (Simple Present)
2. He **is being taken** to the station (Present Continuous)
3. He **has been taken** to the station (Present Perfect)
4. He **was taken** to the station (Simple Past)
5. He **had been taken** to the station (Past Perfect)
6. He **had been being taken** to the station (Past Perfect Continuous)

This last construction is rarely used, and generally found only in grammar books.

See: [Active and Passive Verb Forms](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/activepassive.html) *posted by* EnglishPage.com

---

P.S The OP's grammatically correct sentence would be

> Here is a sentence [which [I think] **is** an example] of **the** passive participle clause.